# TypeError problem: no implicit conversion in Sinatra + JSON.parse

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm trying to set up a web hook, following [this GitHub tutorial](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/)

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'pp'

set :port, 31415

# Descarga las diferencias hechas para un push
post '/' do
  push = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  piezas = push["compare"].split("/")
  api_url = "/repos/#{piezas[3]}/#{piezas[4]}/compare/#{piezas[6]}"
  diff = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://api.github.com#{api_url}"))
  puts diff.class
  pp(JSON.parse(diff))
end
```

`diff.class` prints:

```
String
```

And, as a matter of fact, the last sentence works correctly, printing via `pp` the structure. However, after printing, it yields the error

```
[2018-10-25 20:00:23] ERROR TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
```

It's not referencing any line in the script, but would it be possible that the error would be in the first JSON.parse? Could it be that `request.body.read` would be an array?

*Update* I couldn't golf it down to any of the JSON.parse separately. Downloading the hook payload works OK, downloading the JSON from the GitHub API works without a glithc. Somehow it's using them together what does not work.

Comment: I think we need more of the resp string to be able to help with this. I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: `[11] pry(main)> str = "{\"url\":\"https://api.github.com/repos/JJ/microservices-broker/compare/6149441e1a92...d5d39c5db99d\"}"
=> "{\"url\":\"https://api.github.com/repos/JJ/microservices-broker/compare/6149441e1a92...d5d39c5db99d\"}"`

Comment: `[12] pry(main)> JSON.parse str
=> {"url"=>"https://api.github.com/repos/JJ/microservices-broker/compare/6149441e1a92...d5d39c5db99d"}`

Comment: Done. It's more escaped quotes stuff, but if it helps... Don't quite get what you mean in your last two comments. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I tried `JSON.parse` on the updated string you provided, and it runs fine. Before running `JSON.parse` try `res.body.class` to confirm it's a string. The error may also be elsewhere in your code. It's unlikely github's api is returning a bad json value.

Comment: I too wasn't able to replicate. (And that's what my 2nd and 3rd comment were meant to show. That `JSON.parse` was working fine for me.)

Comment: @JosephCho OK, I'll try to golf it down to a single program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible the library is treating the response like text. Try adding an Accept header. This worked for me:

request["Accept"] = "application/json"

example:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://api.github.com")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(URI("https://api.github.com/repos/JJ/microservices-broker/compare/d5d39c5db99d...bbbf695d1bf2"))
req["Accept"] = 'application/json'
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
response = http.request(req)
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
json['url']

# or 

json = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
json[:url]
```

(EDIT:) Also, Using Net::HTTP is really painful. Please checkout these libraries:

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday
https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb